# html code between a pc and mac changes

Tags: html, macos

I am working with html code for email and coding on a PC, when I send the code to a collaborator on a mac system every white space is converted to a `&nbsp;` and the email is completely corrupted. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Can you show some sample code?

Comment: It's your text encoding. Maybe UTF-8 would work better? But there's no way of us knowing without you telling us. Please expand!

Comment: I guess don't use whatever tool/method/etc. is modifying your code.  Note that we don't know what you're using.

Comment: @ApolloSoftware: I wouldn't expect the text encoding to be HTML-encoding things...

Comment: I've had problems in my .h and .c files across Unreal Engine for Mac vs Windows. Mac tries to use UTF-16 by default and adds weird characters when I open in Windows. Thought it could be applicable w/HTML, since it's applicable in C. But you're probably right @David

Comment: Hi  I am creating the code in a drag & drop email platform editor. When I work with in a PC environment I have no problems. If I send that code to a mac environment all the white spaces become &nbsp; elements withing my html code, this corrupts my email structure. I have been trying to get TextEditor on a macbook to open the file as plain text but that totally removes all html code that is needed. What is the best way to provide you a sample? I haven't sent code to this forum before?

Answer (score 1):

View as HTML not text. the `&nbsp;` is a non-breaking space, so in HTML it looks like a space, but in text it is those 6 characters.

(wow is that really an answer?)

Comment: Without code we don't know if it's plain text, HTML, or whatever encoding.

Comment: Dicovered that textedit on my mac was set as a default for RTF so my files were encoding the white space when transfered to an html editor. I reset prefs to use it as a plain text editro and my problemm was basically resolved. I don't cmpletely understand it but I have a workaround for a client and at the moment that is what I needed